# java,BarSeries:How to Display the Column Chart horizontal?

Tags: java, android, stackedbarseries, column-chart

I want to Display a Column Chart horizontal.I mean I want to change this:[image]
to this:[image] 
but I don't know which properties or function can achieve it.Hope someone could show me the specific code.Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I didn't found properties or function but when I change this:

```
CategoricalAxis horizontalAxis = new CategoricalAxis();
chartView.setHorizontalAxis(horizontalAxis);
LinearAxis verticalAxis = new LinearAxis();
chartView.setVerticalAxis(verticalAxis);
```

to this:

```
CategoricalAxis horizontalAxis = new CategoricalAxis();
chartView.setVerticalAxis(horizontalAxis);
LinearAxis verticalAxis = new LinearAxis();
chartView.setHorizontalAxis(verticalAxis);
```

My problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for this type of layout and it should be scrollable from left to right

[image]

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">



        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Qualities and Criteria"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.2">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Poor (0-50%)"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.2">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Satisfactory (50-70%)"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.2">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Good (70-80%)"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.2">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Excellent (80-150%)"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />
                    </LinearLayout>


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.2">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Marks"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <Button
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:background="@color/white"
                            android:text="Objective, Scope &amp; Project Knowledge (15%)" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button_Objective_poor"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:background="@color/white" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button_Objective_satisfact"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:background="@color/white" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button_Objective_good"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:background="@color/white" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button_Objective_excel"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:background="@color/white" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/et_object"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:hint="Marks" />

                    </LinearLayout>


                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <Button
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:background="@color/white"
                            android:text="Project Significance &amp; Contribution to Society (15%)" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button_project_poor"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:background="@color/white" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button_project_satis"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:background="@color/white" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button_project_good"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:background="@color/white" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button_project_exce"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:background="@color/white" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/et_project"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:hint="Marks" />

                    </LinearLayout>


                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <Button
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:background="@color/white"
                            android:text="Utilization of Engineering/ Problem Solving Skills (20%)" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button_utiliz_poor"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:background="@color/white" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button_utiliz_satis"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:background="@color/white" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button_utiliz_good"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:background="@color/white" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button_utiliz_excel"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:background="@color/white" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/et_util"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:hint="Marks" />

                    </LinearLayout>


                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <Button
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:background="@color/white"
                            android:text="Relevancy &amp; Accuracy (20%)" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button_Relevancy_poor"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:background="@color/white" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button_Relevancy_satisf"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:background="@color/white" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button_Relevancy_good"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:background="@color/white" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button_Relevancy_excel"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:background="@color/white" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/et_relev"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:hint="Marks" />

                    </LinearLayout>


                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <Button
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:background="@color/white"
                            android:text="Presentation Skills (10%)" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button_presen_poor"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:background="@color/white" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button_presen_satis"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:background="@color/white" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button_presen_good"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:background="@color/white" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button_presen_excel"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:background="@color/white" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/et_presen"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:hint="Marks" />

                    </LinearLayout>


                </LinearLayout>



            </LinearLayout>


        </HorizontalScrollView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_Next"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_margin="40dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:text="Next" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but I don't need scrollview,I want to change the column chart vertical to horizontal.